# Redirect to Checkout scrolling to billing details on add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I am trying to achieve a new button on the archive which will add the product to the cart, redirect to the checkout page and scroll down to the billing details.

Nothing happens when using this code:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
function redirect_to_checkout() {
global $woocommerce;
$checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url()#billing_details;
return $checkout_url;
}
```

It gives on error for this line:

```
$checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url()#billing_details;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, your code is outdated and you need to append `#billing_details` as a string like:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
function redirect_to_checkout() {
    return wc_get_checkout_url() . '#billing_details';
}
```

> Now by default `#billing_details` doesn't exist, so you could use instead `#customer_details`

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---